# NODE.JS: Trying to run my first nodejs on atom

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm having some trouble running this simple code on atom:

```
  *var http = require('http');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);*
```

and it shows the following error:

*node:events:498
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
at Object. (C:\Web Development/Max.js:6:4)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Module._compile (C:\Users\20112.atom\packages\script\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:136:24)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\20112.atom\packages\script\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:141:7)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 8080
}*
Any ideas why is this error occuring?

Comment: Some other app is already listening on port 8080. You can change it to some other port.

Answer (score 0):

kill whatever task is running on port 8080

```
npx kill-port 8080
```